# How can I get my QR code, processed with PyQRCode?

Tags: python, reportlab

I am trying to append an image to my pdf. I have successfully appended a barcode but I am having troubles with the QRCode. I am using PyQrCode and ReportLab

Here is my code snippers:

Where I append :

```
parts.append(Image(self.qrCode, width=.3* 0.7 *inch, height=.4*.56*inch))`
```

Where I create the QRCode:

```
qrCode = pyqrcode.create(str("252525"), error='L', version=27, mode='binary')
qrCode.svg(sys.stdout, scale=1)
qrCode.svg('uca-url.svg', scale=4)

number = pyqrcode.create(123456789012345)
number.png('big-number.png')
```

and the error that I am getting:

```
AttributeError at /inventories/download_tag/2525/
QRCode instance has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Is there a better library or method to achieve my goal here?

Comment: reportlab has an internal QRCode widget, maybe that works better for you. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13129015/generate-multiple-qr-codes-in-one-pdf-file-using-reportlab-and-django-framework)

Comment: @MikeScotty thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pyqrcode
```

then

```
cd a_path_you_want
nano  make_qr.py

#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import pyqrcode
text = sys.argv[1]
scale = sys.argv[2] # 1 to 8
err_prt = sys.argv[3] # error_protection in ['L','M','H']
url = pyqrcode.create(text,err_prt)
url.svg(sys.stdout, scale, module_color="brown") #this returns svg to caller script
exit(0)
```

be sure to

```
chmod +x make_qr.py
```

call from php

```
<?php
  $text = ".... your data here ....";
  echo shell_exec("path_to_script/make_qr.py '$text' 4 'L' 2>&1");
 ?>
```